# Astrology and Judiasm

Tags: astrology

Do Jews believe in astrology as an established fact of how Hashem controls the world? Or was it just a superstition that made its way in from the gentile world?

Comment: I think this is a dupe of: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29909/astrology-in-the-torah and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52930/does-the-zodiac-really-have-influence-on-our-lives.